# Recently started getting "Invalid Query"

Tags: google-drive-api

My service that reads and writes from Google Drive has been running for a few years now and there appears to be a subset of users which start a few days ago, started seeing "Invalid query" errors.  The query has not changed:

'[rootFolderId]' in parents and trashed=false and title = 'Filename.csv'

where "[rootFolderId]" is the actual Root Folder Id -- here's a concrete example:

'0AOoKx9EmbosWUk9PVA' in parents and trashed=false and title = 'Filename.csv'

I was unable to reproduce this issue on my personal account.

Does anyone first spot a problem or have any insight into why this may have started being an issue?  Thanks.

Eric

Comment: It appears that the issue is that the corpus on my request was set to DOMAIN and this was causing the issue; switching it to corpus=DEFAULT appears to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Try changing the root folder id to 'root'.